# Using hash to tell positive, odd, even, and negative numbers

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array:

```
    ak = [10, 20, 3, 4, 5, -5, 28, 27]
```

I want a solution like this:

```
    #even:4
    #odd:3
    #positive:7
    #negative:1
```

How do I use hash to do that?

Comment: I did not notice that he excluded negative numbers until @sid commented, since the obvious way is to just go the naturel way, and include all the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (based on the output that you expect) that you only want the positive even or odd numbers:

```
h = Hash.new
h["even"] = ak.select {|x| x.even? && x > 0}.count
h["odd"] = ak.select {|x| x.odd? && x > 0}.count
h["positive"] = ak.select {|x| x > 0}.count
h["negative"] = ak.select {|x| x < 0}.count

puts h
```

Comment: Take a look to my solution, it has a more succinct and clearer code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no worries, `even?` and `odd?` are definitely better so thanks for those suggestions. I've also edited my answer to be clear about my assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this in a fairly general (reusable) way as follows.

**Code**

```
def analyze_array(ak, ops)
  ops.each_with_object({}) { |(k,m),h| h.update(k=>ak.count(&m)) }
end
```

**Example**

```
ak = [10, 20, 3, 4, 5, -5, 28, 27]

ops = [[:even,     :even?       ],
       [:odd,      :odd?        ],
       [:positive, ->(n) { n>0 }],
       [:negative, ->(n) { n<0 }]]

analyze_array(ak, ops)
  #=> {:even=>4, :odd=>4, :positive=>7, :negative=>1}
```

**Explanation**

For the example above:

```
enum = ops.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:even, :even?], [:odd, :odd?],
  #    [:positive, #<Proc:0x007fe90395aaf8@(irb):9 (lambda)>],
  #    [:negative, #<Proc:0x007fe90395aaa8@(irb):10 (lambda)>]]
  #     :each_with_object({})>
```

Note that `:even?` and `:odd?` are symbols (not to be confused with methods).

The elements of `enum` are passed into the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each). We can see what the elements of `enum` are by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[:even, :even?], {}], [[:odd, :odd?], {}],
  #    [[:positive, #<Proc:0x007fe90395aaf8@(irb):9 (lambda)>], {}],
  #    [[:negative, #<Proc:0x007fe90395aaa8@(irb):10 (lambda)>], {}]]
```

and simulate the passing of the (`4`) elements of `enum` into the block with [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). The first element of `enum` (`[[:even, :even?], {}]`) is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables:

```
(k,m),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:even, :even?], {}] 
k #=> :even 
m #=> :even? 
h #=> {}
```

Next, we use [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/H-update) (aka `merge!`) to merge a one-key hash into `h` and return the new value of `h`:

```
h.update(k=>ak.count(&m))
  #=> {}.update(:even=>[10, 20, 3, 4, 5, -5, 28, 27].count(&:even?))
  #=> {:even=>4}
```

(Ruby allows us to write `(k=>ak.count(&m))` as shorthand for  `({k=>ak.count(&m)})`).

As usual, `&` invokes [Symbol#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) to convert the symbol `:even?` to a proc and then converts the proc to a block for `count`.

The next value of `enum` is then passed to the block ("odd"), similar calculations are performed and the hash `{ :odd=>4 }` is merged into `h`, resulting in:

```
h #=> { :even=>4, :odd=>4 }
```

The third and fourth values of `enum` are then passed to the block. The only difference is that `m` in `ak.count(&m)` is already a proc (a lambda, actually), so `&` just converts it to a block for `count`.

Comment: Really a good solution, I was about to make my answer this way, but I recurred to a more direct solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
   h = Hash.new
   h["even"] = ak.select {|x| x.even? && x > 0}.count
   h["odd"] = ak.select {|x| x.odd? && x > 0}.count
   h["positive"] = ak.select {|x| x > 0}.count
   h["negative"] = ak.select {|x| x < 0}.count
```

and add

```
 put h
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
ak = [10, 20, 3, 4, 5, -5, 28, 27]
akp = ak.select{ |n| n > 0 }
h = {
  even: akp.count(&:even?),
  odd: akp.count(&:odd?),
  positive: akp.count,
  negative: ak.count{ |n| n < 0 }
}
puts ak, h
```

Comment: Nice didn't realize you could use `.count` that way! However I believe OP wants only wants positive numbers for even and odd.

Comment: Ah ok, only consider positive numbers when counting even and odd. ok.

Comment: No take a look at my answer - it would be that except using just .count as you have

Comment: @PauloFidalgo Thank you, just was some what enthusiastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over you array and test each value like this:

```
def evaluate(array)
  response = { even: 0, odd: 0, positive: 0, negative: 0 }
  array.each do |item|
    response[:even] += 1 if item.even?
    response[:odd] += 1 if item.odd?
    ...
  end
  response
end
```

Or something like that. You can optimize it after.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate(arr)
   even = arr.select {|e| e.even?}.size
   odd = arr.select {|e| e.odd?}.size
   pos = arr.select {|e| e >= 0}.size
   neg = arr.select {|e| e < 0}.size

   hash = {even: even, odd: odd, positive: pos, negative:neg}
end
```